# Trying to figure out where ssh port forwarding is configured in vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to learn Vagrant, Ansible, and Jenkins, so I was super stoked when I came across [this repo](https://github.com/ernesen/infra-ansible). A lot of the code is out of date so I've spent my time updating things and it is almost running perfect. The one issue I can't figure out is how/where he is defining the port forwarding for SSH.

For example, when I boot up the nfsserver, I see this line:

`nfsserver.sample.com: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)`

But when I boot up the nfsclient, I see this line:

`nfsclient.sample.com: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.`

I've looked through all of his files (even used grep -r) and for the life of me, I can't figure out where he's defining these values.

I found [this article](https://realguess.net/2015/10/06/overriding-the-default-forwarded-ssh-port-in-vagrant/) that mentions the config.vm.network, but I don't see that called anywhere in the Vagrantfile I'm working with.

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out where this is defined so I can change the values. I (and the others I want to show this to) already have 2222 mapped.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the default behaviour of vagrant, it is not from your configuration file.

since you run multiple VM and for each of the guest VM you want to forward the ssh port (22) on the host, the default value for the host is 2222. The first VM you boot takes this value. But afterwards for following VM which want to forward their 22 port to the 2222 host port, it is not possible as host 2222 is already bound (to the 1st VM) vagrant is then using other values (by default it is using the 2200..2250 range but you can configure that - see link to doc)

This is probably better explained in the [Port Collisions and Correction](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports#port-collisions-and-correction) part of the vagrant doc.